# Why does passing char** as const char** generate a warning?

Tags: c, gcc

I've been getting this warning:

```
note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

For now, I'm passing the arguments by casting them to `const char **`. Is there any other way I can get rid of it?

Comment: Could you provide the function prototype you are using?

Comment: Sure. `int CompareRecords(const char **, const char **, 
     const int *, const int)`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Can you safely typecast `char **` to `const char**`? ***No***. (Not safely anyway), and the reason is far more subtle than you may think. Can you get rid of it another way? Sure. Load an array of `const char*` values from your `char*` values and pass that instead. (or change the callee prototype, but thats cheating =P).

Consider the following code, which essentially does everything you're wishing *except* invoke a function. The marked line demonstrates the equivalent point-of-cast

```
const char *s = "Test";
char *p = NULL;
char **pp = &p;             // Put address of our pointer in our pointer-to-pointer.
const char **cpp = pp;      // Here: assigning  char** to const char**
*cpp = s;                   // perfectly legal; pp and s both finish "char const"
*p = 0;                     // ru ro raggy
```

It takes awhile to really stare at this, and admittedly I didn't see it at first either. @sheu did a solid job of catching it about 24 hours before I really thought about it long enough to realize he was right all along (and I actually upvoted that answer before writing this one). Then I thought he was wrong about the same time he thought his answer wasn't applicable. Turns out we were *both* wrong on that leap, because he was right the first time, I was wrong the second time, and now... ugh.

On VS2012 and VS2010 both the marked line will flag an error without a cast. **clang** will compile it with a warning in C, but allow it (which I found surprising). Given, you do have to really step out of your happy place to break it, but it is still none-the-less broken.

The rest of this is a diatribe on identifying pointer types, their constness, and what is equivalent to what.

---

**Long Diatribe on Pointers And Const**

The warning is because `char **` and `const char **` are not equivalent (duh). To be correct, you could fix the prototype (callee), or fix the caller (by loading an array of `const char *` and passing that). But can you safely typecast the first to the second? Hmmm....

Remember, by the standard `const` goes to the item immediately to its *left*. Declaring it on the most-left of a data type is a nicety that the language supports, but often introduces confusion or problems. As a rule-of-thumb, if `const` appears on the far-left of a decl immediately before the type, it applies to the data *type*; **not** the subsequent pointer (if any). When it appears to the right *of anything* it applies to the immediate-left decl-part, be it a data type part *or* a pointer part, but no matter what it only applies to a *single* part.

A plethora of samples follows:

**No Indirection**:

```
const char ch;    // const character. must be initialized.
char const ch;    // same as above
```

**Single-Indirection**:

```
char *p;               // p is mutable, *p is mutable
const char *p;         // p is mutable, *p is const
char const *p;         // same as above.
char *const p;         // p is const, *p is mutable, must be initialized.
char const *const p;   // p is const, *p is const, must be initialized.
```

**Double Indirection**:

```
char **p;        // ptr-to-ptr-to-char
                 // p, *p, and **p are ALL mutable

const char **p;  // ptr-to-ptr-to-const-char
                 // p and *p are mutable, **p is const

char const **p;  // same as above

char *const *p;  // ptr-to-const-ptr-to-char
                 // p is mutable, *p is const, **p is mutable.

char **const p;  // const-ptr-to-ptr-to-char
                 // p is const, *p is mutable, **p is mutable.
                 // must be initialized.

const char **const p;  // const-ptr-to-ptr-to-const-char
                       // p is const, *p is mutable, **p is const.
                       // must be initialized.

char const **const p;  // same as above

char const *const *p;  // ptr-to-const-ptr-to-const-char
                       // p is mutable, *p is const, **p is const.

const char *const *p;  // same as above.

char *const *const p;  // const-ptr-to-const-ptr-to-char
                       // p is const, *p is const, **p is mutable.
                       // must be initialized.
```

And of course who can leave home without...

```
char const *const *const p;   // const-ptr-to-const-ptr-to-const-char
                              // everything is const.
                              // must be initialized.

const char *const *const p;   // same as above
```

So how does this affect your question? When compiling that code in C, without a cast you'll get a compiler warning (or error if compiling with `-Werror`). When compiling in C++, you'll just plain error because the parameter signature doesn't match. But why?

Because these have no direct equivalence:

```
const char **p;  // ptr-to-ptr-to-const-char
                 // p and *p are mutable **p is const

char **p;        // ptr-to-ptr-to-char
                 // p, *p, and **p are all mutable
```

When compiling with **clang**, the exact warning in C is given as:

> main.c:15:9: Passing `char **` to parameter of type `const char **` discards qualifiers in nested pointer types.

VS2010 and VS2012 both, on the other hand, toss an error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char **' to 'const char **'

It seems odd, but VS is actually more correct (wonders never cease).

And that makes perfect sense. Nestled down in the type declaration is the fact that the first of these does not allow modification to the final data, the second *does*. From above we know that `char **` and `const char **` (aka. `char const **`), are *not* the same. At the bottom of one is a pointer to a `const char`, while the other has a pointer to `char`.

Comment: Note that casting to `char const * const *` IS safe (since you cannot change what it points to).  (I've verified this using OCaml's type system.)  Unfortunately the GCC folks seem to have used the big hammer approach in disallowing ALL such casts, and Clang seems to have copied them.

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks, Chris. After rereading what I wrote now over three-months past I can't believe I left that out (and yet I included the last example, which is differs by making the base pointer const, duh). I'll try and update the answer to reflect that addition. Thanks again. Edit: I didn't leave it out. Its there, but you're point on the safety  would seem accurate.

Comment: Even so, why is it an error? Can the compiler simply not check to see we are not modifying the characters in that function invocation? I thought the point of `const` was to make the compiler enforce a certain thing. From my understanding, passing `char **` to a `const char**` simply says that in that function, we won't modify the characters.

Answer (score 44):

This is a fun bit of C, which makes sense if you think hard enough about it.

Basically, the conversion:

```
char** ptr;
const char** const_ptr;
const_ptr = ptr;  // <-- BAD!
```

is not allowed.

Why, you might ask?  "I'm making things *more* const!  This is obviously a good thing!"

---

Well, think about this.  If that were allowed, then:

```
const char c = 'A';
char* ptr;
const char** const_ptr = &ptr;  // <-- ILLEGAL, but what if this were legal?
*const_ptr = &c;
*ptr = 'B';  // <- you just assigned to "const char c" above.
```

BAM you're dead.  So... no :-)

Comment: +1 (a long time ago,but its worth mentioning). This was the answer that ultimately made mine work, and if the casual reader hasn't already done so, it certainly deserves a vote.

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you that the function you're calling expects the given parameter as `const char**` but you're passing a `char**` parameter. To get rid of this warning you could

- really pass in a `const char**`
- cast your parameter to a `const char**` (like you're currently doing)
- change the function prototype so that the function expects a `char**`

Comment: As a third option I would better change the function prototype to `const char * const *`, if the function does not need to change the chars.