# When to use const* versus const * const?

Tags: c

I have seen code where people will use const as a parameter to the function. What are the benefits of using const* vs const * const? This might be a very basic question but I would appreciate if someone could explain.

```
Bool IsThisNumberEqualToFive(int const * num)
{
    return(Bool)(5 != num );
}

Bool IsThisNumberEqualToFive(int const * const num)
{
    return(Bool)(5 != num );
}
```

Comment: Somewhat related: You may find [this answer to a previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning/14566215#14566215) interesting. not directly related to your question, so not a dupe, but check out the pointer-type list and the effects of `const`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In the first version you promise you're not going to write to the
  object that `num` points to
- In the second version you promise that and you also prevent yourself
  (i.e. IsThisNumber..) from making `num` point to something else.

That is, in the second version **the pointer itself is also `const`**, in addition to the pointee.

Comment: So In a function like where we just have to check whether a statement is true or not (We are not changing anything inside the function)we should use the second option ?

Comment: Technically it allows the compiler to optimize more. In practice you care more about the pointee-level const.

Comment: @user968000 Personally I consider top level `const`s like the one in the second function pretty much worthless. Someone calling that function doesn't care whether you do `++num;` within the function, but they're more likely to care that you don't do `*num = 42;`, which the first version promises you won't.

Comment: @user968000 Your code should also reflect the dereference of `*num`, which it currently does not. As written, unless your pointer contains an address `0x00000005` (highly unlikely), the function will always return `true`. I believe you wanted to use `*num` in those evals.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good call!

Comment: @cnicutar Heh. not your problem, your answer is *solid*. Just there for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

For the parameter

```
int const * num  // num is a pointer to const int.
```

const is protecting the `num` points to.The program can alter the value of `num` but not `*num`. While for

```
int const * const num  // num is a const pointer to const int
```

leftmost `const` is protecting the `num` points to while right most is protecting pointer `num` it self. In this case neither `num` nor `*num` is going to modify.

**NOTE:** Understanding what does

```
T const *p;  // T is any valid type
```

means (more precisely).
This means that, a program can use the expression `p` to alter the value of the pointer object that `p` designates, but it can’t use the expression `*p` to alter the value of any objects that `*p` might designate. **If the program has another expression `e` of unqualified type that designates an object that `*p` also designates,the program can still use `e` to change that object**.

Comment: @ViktorLexington; In first case pointer can be changed but not the value pointed by the pointer. For second example you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The more the sources tell the compiler on what will happend  to variables' values (or better "**not** happen" as it would be expected for `const` variables) in advance the better the compiler can optmise.