# Rules of const: what's allowed and whats not?

Tags: c

I have found the `const` rules in c to be very confusing. I want to know if there are known rules or a way to know what's allowed when dealing with `const`/pointers to `const`.

I will give an exmple:

Not allowed:

```
const int b=3;

int * const a=&b;
```

Allowed:

```
int b=3;

int * const a=&b;
```

Are there rules to know before compiling if the code that contain `const` will compile? One thing I though about is -- and I want to know if it's a rule -- every time you write a line with `const`, does there always have to be initialize after it?  I know that there is some rule about what `const` can/can't hold.

Comment: What's the problem? You can convert a `T *` to a `U *` iff `U` is an equally or more CV-qualified version of `T`.

Comment: -1. You can be reasonably expected to spell the only important word in your question correctly.

Comment: `int *const` is a constant pointer to a variable int, you seem to be looking for a variable pointer to a constant int (`const int *` or `int const *`) or a constant pointer to a constant int (`const int *const`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use const\* versus const \* const?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097690/when-to-use-const-versus-const-const)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example:

```
const int b=3;
// int * const a=&b; ERROR: cannot cast "const int *" to "int *".
const int *const a = &b;
```

You have to unwrap the declaration.

- The type `int *const` is a *constant pointer* to a mutable `int`.
- The type `const int *` is a mutable pointer to a constant `int`.
- The type `const int *const` is a constant pointer to a constant `int`.

You can't assign if the left-hand side of the assignment is a constant (by which I mean, "has a type with the `const` qualifier").  So,

```
int *x = ...;
x = ...; // ok, RHS must be int *
*x = ...; // ok, RHS must be int

int *const x = ...;
x = ...; // error
*x = ...; // ok, RHS must be int

const int *x = ...;
x = ...; // ok, RHS may be int * or const int *
*x = ...; // error

const int *const x = ...;
x = ...; // error
*x = ...; // error
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't really with `const` itself, it's with not being able to understand what variables hold.

declaring something as `const` means that the value will not be changed. So:

```
const int b=3;
```

Now `b` holds `3` and you can't assign it something else, because it's constant. The same holds true for pointers:

```
int b=3;
int * const a=&b;
```

The pointer `a` is now pointing to the address of `b`, you can't assign a different address there now. The reason that this:

```
const int b=3;
int * const a=&b;
```

doesn't work is because `a` is a constant pointer to a (non-constant) `int`. Yet you're trying to assign `a` the value of a constant `int`. So the compiler says, "no".

```
const int b=3;
const int * a=&b;
```

This change now allows it to work, because `a` is a pointer to a constant-int, which is what `b` is, so it's OK to make the assignment. If you want both `a` and `b` to be constant you need to make the second line:

```
const int * const a=&b;
```

You're running into an issue with the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Answer (score 1):

The basic rules are:

- It is okay to add `const` (when casting or otherwise converting).
- It is okay to remove `const` **only** if it is a `const` that was added later, not a `const` that an object was initially defined with.

Examples:

```
int a = 3;
const int b = 4;

// Okay, adds const (says the int is const).
const int *p0 = (const int *) &a;

// Okay, adds const (says the pointer to the int is const).
int * const p1 = (int * const) &a;

// Okay, removes an added const.
int *p2 = (int *) p0;

// Not okay, removes a defined const.
int *p3 = (int *) &b;
```