# Difference between the following declarations and definitions

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, constants, string-literals

According to my textbook,

1. char *p = "hello";

   - A pointer to a string where both the string and the pointer can be modified
2. const char *p = "hello";

   - A pointer to a constant string where the string cannot be manipulated but the pointer can be manipulated to point to another char string
3. char *const p = "hello";

- A constant pointer to a string where the string can be manipulated but the pointer cannot be manipulated to point to another char string

4. const char *const p = "hello";

- both the string or the pointer cannot be changed.

But here are my output for the different cases when the string can be modified -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
     char *p = "hello";
    *p = 'a';
    //p = "bye";
    printf("%s",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output : Segmentation Fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    char *const p = "hello";
    *p = 'a';
    //p = "bye";
    printf("%s",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: Segmentation Fault

When do I get a segmentation fault in these cases when almost all the references I came across says otherwise? Thanks.[image][image]

Comment: Does your text book really say _"A constant pointer to a string **where the string can be manipulated** but the pointer cannot be manipulated to point to another char string"_ about `char *const t = "hello";`? Edit: Yes, I see that it does. It even says `*t = 'M'; /* works */` - which has UB.

Comment: How old is that book? Does it mention any particular C standard?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo - I think Vlad's answer cleared it up. The book is pretty old :D

Comment: The main problem here is the book is not in the trash can. `char *p = "Hello"; *p = 'M';` is symptomatic of somebody who did poorly as a C programmer yet decided to teach anyway. The C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to modify data in a string literal even if it is pointed to with a pointer of type `char *`.

Comment: This is from the infamous "Let Us C" book, written by this dude who keeps publishing one programming book each month or so. Clearly the publisher went with quantity over quality there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though in C opposite to C++ string literals have types of non-constant character arrays nevertheless you may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C17 Stndard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Sp it is better in C to declare  pointers to string literals with the qualifier `const` as for example

```
const char *p = "hello";
```

If a pointer (without the qualifier `const`) points to a non-constant array then you may change the array using the pointer. For example

```
char s[] = "hello";
char *p = s;
*p = 'a';
```

So it will be better and correct to rewrite all your examples using an intermediate array as shown above. For example

```
char s[] = "hello";
const char *p = s;
*p = 'a'; // compiler error
          // trying to modify array through a pointer with the qualifier const

 *s = 'a'; // correct; the array itself is not constant
```

Comment: Thanks. But that example in the picture tells otherwise. Also, what is the difference between char *p and const char *p if that is the case ?

Comment: @blazingcannon Declaring a pointer as const char * means that you may not change an object pointed to by the pointer using the pointer.

Comment: Isn't that what char *p is also doing ? It is not allowing me to modify what is pointed to by p

Comment: @blazingcannon See my appended answer.

Comment: You answered an exact duplicate back in 2014 (seems to be the same book even). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158716/the-const-qualifier-and-const-pointers. Consider closing as duplicate instead of answering these FAQ questions.

Answer (score 0):

> But here are my output for the different cases when the string can be
> modified -
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int main() {
>     // Write C code here
>      char *p = "hello";
>     *p = 'a';
>     //p = "bye";
>     printf("%s",p);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

No, it is Undefined Behaviour as *string literals* cannot be modified. So, this example is invalid.

Your book is completely wrong and should not be used to learn C. All the examples show the author's lack of C knowledge.

1. You can't modify string literals (ie "fgfdfdgfgfdg")
2. You cant modify const objects.
3. If you try to modify const object via pointer to not const object you invoke **Undefined Bahavior** and your program is not valid anymore.