# what is the second const doing in "const int const &someval"?

Tags: c++

talking about a function parameter, for example:

```
void doSomething(const int const &someVal);
```

As far as I understand, the fist const indicates that the value will not be changed by the function, and the & indicates that the value should be passed by reference. But what does the second 'const' do?

Comment: It irritates, confuses, and causes [compiler diagnostics](http://ideone.com/ZYakRQ).

Comment: Make the program ill-formed?

Comment: It's holding the candle.

Comment: Soo.. it should not be there? Hey, its not my code, I'm just working off an example.

Comment: The first `const` placement is a syntax nicety provided by the standard when *openning* a def. It *does* what the second `const` is already doing. `int const& someVal` and `const int& someVal` are synonymous. Remove *either* .

Comment: @0x499602D2: That a fact? (It's certainly bad)

Comment: In `const int const *someVal`, both `const`s are meaningful. Perhaps the author mistakenly though that the same was true for references. (References are loosely similar to `const` pointers.)

Comment: @KeithThompson even in that the second `const` is duplicate. If you meant `const int *const someVal;`, synonymous with `int const * const someVal;` then yeah, that holds, so long as the second `const` is *after* the `*`.

Comment: @Deduplicator GCC reported an error. And now I look at it I see clang gave a warning.

Comment: @WhozCraig: You're right.

Comment: @The double-indirection chart in an [answer I wrote a long time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14566215/1322972) somewhat chiseled it in my head. I particularly liked the *last* one in the list. Thought about making T-shirts: "Got `const`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (7.1.6.1 The cv-qualifiers)

> 1 There are two cv-qualifiers, const and volatile. **Each cv-qualifier
>   shall appear at most once in a cvqualifier- seq**. If a cv-qualifier
>   appears in a decl-specifier-seq, the init-declarator-list of the
>   declaration shall not be empty. [ Note: 3.9.3 and 8.3.5 describe how
>   cv-qualifiers affect object and function types. —end note ]
>   **Redundant cv-qualifications are ignored.** [ Note: For example, these could be introduced by typedefs.—end note ]

So this declaration

```
void doSomething(const int const &someVal);
```

has a redundant const qualifier that is simply ignored.

The second const qualifier would have a sense if `someVal` would be declared as a reference to const pointer. For example

```
void doSomething(const int * const &someVal);
```

Comment: It's not just ignored. `const int const` is ill-formed by 7.1.6 [dcl.type]/p2, first bullet point: "`const` can be combined with any type specifier _except itself_." (emphasis added).

Answer (score 0):

Both of these should work:

```
void doSomething(const int &someVal);

void doSomething(int const &someVal);
```

Using a second const doesn't add any functionality and the extra one should be removed. It's a good practice to keep the const to the left though for clarity as it stands out better.