# const int pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I am learning about constant pointers and I was trying this

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std ;
int main(){
    int a = 10 ; 
    const int *cp  = &a ;               // my constant pointer variable
    cout<<"\nAddress stored in cp = "<<cp ;
    ++cp;
    cout<<"\nAddress stored in cp = "<<cp   ;
}
```

It incremented the address which was stored in `cp`
But according to what I have understood until now, shouldn't `++cp` give an error as it is a constant pointer that always points to the same address and this address cannot be modified.

But when I replaced

`const int *cp  = &a ;`   with   `int *const cp  = &a ;`

It gives me this
[image]

Forgive my ignorance but, aren't they suppose to mean the same thing ?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html

Comment: Personally I dislike the *spiral* approach to reading types, I would recommend that you place `const` in the *right* (correct) place, which is to the *right* (as opposed to *left*) of the type being `const`, in the code above: `int const *` and `int * const`. Then read from right to left.

Comment: @chris: Spiral Rule is WRONG. Listen to David Rodriguez

Comment: @kotlomoy, The spiral rule has not once failed me in reading a type. The only exception is really this cv qualifier being allowed to go on the left. If I could rename it, I'd prefer something like the Alternating Right-Left Rule, but once you understand the technique, you'll be hard-pressed to find something you can't read.

Comment: @chris: "you'll be hard-pressed to find something you can't read." - `int a[2][3]`. For info: I wasn't pressed at all

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing   `int *const cp  = &a;` it means a integer pointer to a constant cp, so cp cannot change. However, in your previous version `const int *cp` means a constant int pointer to cp, so the value where cp points cannot change, but the pointer itself can.

Usually, people like to read this from right to left:

`const int *cp` cp is a pointer to a int constant, so the integer number cannot change.

`int *const cp  = &a;` cp is a constant pointer to an int, so the pointer cannot change.

Answer (score 2):

```
const int *cp  = &a ;
```

Content of address pointed by `cp` is read-only, however pointer `cp` is not

So,

```
*cp = value ; //Illegal
++cp ; // Legal
```

---

```
int *const cp = &a ;
```

Pointer is read-only, however content of address pointed by `cp` is not

So,

```
*cp = value ; //Legal
++cp ; // Illegal
```

---

Also,

```
const int *const cp  = &a ;
```

Both pointer as well as content of address pointed by `cp` are read-only

```
*cp = value ; //Illegal
++cp ; // Illegal
```

For simple declaration *read from right to left*

- [`const int *cp ;`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+int+*cp+%3B)
- [`int *const cp ;`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+*const+cp+%3B)
- [`const int *const cp ;`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=const+int+*const+cp+%3B)

Answer (score 1):

```
const int *cp1  = &a ; // pointer is variable, pointed to is constant
int *const cp2  = &a ; // pointer is constant, pointed to is variable
const int *const cp3  = &a ; // pointer is constant, pointed to is constant
```

Thus,

```
cp1++; // possible
*cp1++; // not possible
cp2++; // not possible
*cp2++; // possible
cp3++; // not possible
*cp3++; // not possible
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps at all (and it probably doesn't), the following are synonymous, taking advantage of a language nicety that allows an opening type to have  `const` appear on the immediate left *or* right of the type, but before any additional qualifiers (like pointers or references):

```
const int * p; // does NOT require initialization
int const * q; // same as above
```

Both declare pointers to constant `int` data, and are interchangeable in syntax.

Whereas this:

```
int * const p = &a; // requires initialization.
```

declares a constant pointer to `int` data; *not* a pointer to constant `int` data.

Extending this further (actually *merging* them both), we get:

```
const int * const p = &a;
int const * const p = &a;
```

These are synonymous. Both declare a constant pointer to constant int data. Neither the pointer, nor what it points *to* are modifiable, and both require initialization.

---

**Shamelessly Ripped Off Chart**

The following was shamelessly ripped off from.. myself (ok, not that much shame), from a *slightly* related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning). I hope it helps further explain the differences in what happens when you position `const` and `*` in different places of a declaration:

**Single-Indirection**:

```
char *p;               // p is mutable, *p is mutable
const char *p;         // p is mutable, *p is const
char const *p;         // same as above.
char *const p;         // p is const, *p is mutable, must be initialized.
char const *const p;   // p is const, *p is const, must be initialized.
```

**Double Indirection**:

```
char **p;        // ptr-to-ptr-to-char
                 // p, *p, and **p are ALL mutable

const char **p;  // ptr-to-ptr-to-const-char
                 // p and *p are mutable, **p is const

char const **p;  // same as above

char *const *p;  // ptr-to-const-ptr-to-char
                 // p is mutable, *p is const, **p is mutable.

char **const p;  // const-ptr-to-ptr-to-char
                 // p is const, *p is mutable, **p is mutable.
                 // must be initialized.

const char **const p;  // const-ptr-to-ptr-to-const-char
                       // p is const, *p is mutable, **p is const.
                       // must be initialized.

char const **const p;  // same as above

char const *const *p;  // ptr-to-const-ptr-to-const-char
                       // p is mutable, *p is const, **p is const.

const char *const *p;  // same as above.

char *const *const p;  // const-ptr-to-const-ptr-to-char
                       // p is const, *p is const, **p is mutable.
                       // must be initialized.
```

And my personal favorite:

```
char const *const *const p;   // const-ptr-to-const-ptr-to-const-char
                              // everything is const.
                              // must be initialized.

const char *const *const p;   // same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons I always recommend placing the `const` on the right of the `int` not the left.  As in:

```
int const *cp;
```

and not:

```
const int *cp;
```

That has the advantage that the item that is made `const` is what's on the right of the `const` keyword, *and it's type is on the left.*

In the above, *cp (i.e. the contents of cp) is const, and it's type is int.  If you write

```
int * const cp = &foo;
```

and apply the same rules, `cp` is `const` and the `const` item has type `int *`.  When there are multiple levels of indirection, using this rule makes it far easier to understand what's happening.

```
int const ** cpp1;
int * const *cpp2;
int ** const cpp3 = &bar;
int const ** const cpp4 = &xyz;
```

That last one is a `const` pointer to a mutable pointer to a `const int`.  And one `const` item has type `int` while the other has type `int **`.  Trivial to understand, as long as you never place the word `const` on the left of the `int`.