# const char * vs. const char ** function argument

Tags: c, gcc-warning

I've read the [C FAQ on const](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html), but I'm still confused.

I was under the (apparently mistaken) impression that const in a function declaration was essentially a promise that the function won't modify what you have marked as const.  Thus passing in a const or not-const parameter is fine.  But this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void f1 ( const char * cc );
extern void f2 ( const char ** ccc );

int main ( void ) {
    char            c1[]    = "hello";
    const char *    c2      = "hello";
    char *          c3      = NULL;
    char **         v1      = NULL;
    const char **   v2      = NULL;

    f1( c1 );               /* ok */
    f1( c2 );               /* ok */
    f1( c3 );               /* ok */
    f1( "hello, world" );   /* ok */
    f2( v1 );               /* compiler warning - why? */
    f2( v2 );               /* ok */
    return 0;
}
```

warns thusly:

```
$ cc -c -o sample.o sample.c sample.c: In function 'main': sample.c:17:
warning: passing argument 1 of 'f2' from incompatible pointer type
sample.c:4: note: expected 'const char **' but argument is of type 'char **'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning

Comment: None of those answers have any function examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard forbids this, because that would allow to violate constness of an object. Consider:

```
const char ch = 'X';
char* ch_ptr;
const char** ch_pptr = &ch_ptr; // This is not allowed, because...

*ch_pptr = &ch;
*ch_ptr = 'Q'; // ...this will modify ch, which should be immutable!
```

After this line:

`const char** ch_pptr = &ch_ptr;`

`*ch_pptr` and `ch_ptr` yield the same value (address), but they are of different types (`const char*` and `char*`). Then, you use `ch_pptr` to point const object, which automatically cause `ch_ptr` to point to the same memory location. By doing this, you allowed for any modification (using `ch_ptr`) of an object, that was initially declared an constant.

This error is very subtle, but after a while, you should be able to understand why it could be dangerous. That's why it is not allowed.

---

> Yes, but why is not putting the const in the function declaration the "promise" that the function does not do that sort of evil?

Because it works the other way around - function, that does perfectly legal things may introduce invalid behavior. Look at this code:

```
static const char* sample_string = "String";

void f2 (const char ** ccc)
{
    *ccc = sample_string; //Perfectly valid - function does not do any "evil" things
}

int main ( void )
{
    char** v1 = NULL;

    f2(v1); // After this call, *v1 will point to sample_string

    (*v1)[0] = 'Q'; // Access violation error

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why is not putting the const in the function declaration the "promise" that the function does not do that sort of evil?

Comment: Because it's not the function who would cause the harm - that's the case. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense where the answers to previous questons did not.

Comment: Oddly, using `const char * const * ccc` gives the same warning though it prevents the assignment to `*ccc` in `f2()`

Comment: Second `const` refers to constness of the *first-level pointer*, so it can't work. `const char** const` will be fine, however.

Comment: Hmmm, "cdecl.org" disagrees -- it says 'const char * const * cccc' is 'declare cccc as pointer to const pointer to const char` and 'const char ** const cccc' is 'declare cccc as const pointer to pointer to const char'

Answer (score 0):

```
f2( v1 );               /* compiler warning - why? */
```

> compiler warning - why?

Because `char**` and `const char**` are different. They are not treated as same.

```
char** v1 // pointer to pointer to char
```

Here you can change value of `**v1` .

Whereas

```
const char** v2  //pointer to pointer to constant char
```

Here you can't change value of `**v2` and if you try to compiler issues a error.

Comment: nope, that's not why. it should be fine to pass a modifiable object to a function that even promises not to modify it. The subtle problem lies elsewhere, one level of indirection above.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant  Compiler won't treat them as same. So to that my answer was.