# Why does calling a function that accepts a (const char * const **) with a char *** raise a -Wcast-qual flag?

Tags: c, pointers, types, qualifiers

If we have `void foo(const char * const ** bar);` and we call it with `char *** bar = malloc(...);` such as `foo((const char * const **) bar);` It returns:

```
error: to be safe all intermediate pointers in cast from ‘char ***’ to ‘const char * const**’ must be ‘const’ qualified [-Werror=cast-qual]
```

Trying to pass it in without casting results in a type warning, but passing a `char *` into a `const char *` *works*, I can also pass a `char ***` into a `char ** const *` function parameter, but I want more read-only qualifier than just a single level.

The **intent** is that the function assumes the entire pointer data and pointer being passed in are read-only, such that the pointer won't be written to in any way.

I understand that the flag is an extra one, but it's defined as:

```
-Wcast-qual

Warn whenever a pointer is cast so as to remove a type qualifier from the target type. For example, warn if a const char * is cast to an ordinary char *.
```

As far as I can tell, no type qualifier is being removed, rather we're *adding* type qualifiers to let the user know that the function doesn't change any data.

**Why is the previously mentioned code triggering the extra warning -Wcast-qual?** Is there a better way of going about passing a completely malloc'd triple pointer as a read-only function?

Comment: `Is there a better way of going about passing a completely malloc'd triple pointer as a read-only function?` Yes, don't cast `malloc` at all

Comment: Casting raises a "incompatible pointer type" error. I actually agree, it makes no sense to cast, but for some reason the compiler won't allow it.
EDIT: Is a const char * const ** not the same type as char *** just with qualifiers?

Comment: Are you compiling with a C++ compiler?

Comment: @jake Related, it may help if you make the problem just a wee bit simpler. See [Why does passing `char**` as `const char**` generate a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning),

Comment: Compiling with GCC  5.2.1 std=c11 so a C compiler

Comment: "Is there a better way of going about passing a completely malloc'd triple pointer as a read-only function?"  --> Why not `const char * const ** bar = malloc(sizeof *bar * N); foo2(bar);` and avoid all casting?

Comment: I can't do that because I wish to actually malloc further and give all cells memory. If I try to do `bar[0] = malloc` I'll get `assignment of read-only location`. Also, I think mallocing into const memory is considered bad practice because you're going to free it later, so it should never be read-only.

Comment: `bar[0] = malloc(...)` is not a problem.  `bar[0][0] = malloc()` is an issue.  As "The intent is that the function assumes the entire pointer data and pointer being passed in are read-only" I suspect you wanted another `const` --> `foo(const char * const * const * bar)`

Comment: Does this work for you? 1) `foo(const char * const ** bar)` --> `foo(const char * const * const *  bar)` 2) `foo((const char * const **) bar);` --> `foo((const char * const * const*) bar);`.  Add `const` to both function and cast.

Comment: Chux, that seems to work. Thank you very much. Can you make that an answer fully and I can reward you the points. I didn't realize that the `const **` != `const * const *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
`const char * const **` -> `const char * const * const *`

To finish the question, answered in the comments by /users/2410359/chux (asked them to make a post, but they haven't). The solution was to use a `const char * const * const *` which does not trigger the `-Wcast-qual` flag. Basically what I had was not true read-only qualifiers, I needed another level.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does passing a `char*` to a function that expects a `char const*` work?

It's simple to understand that. You are not able to modify the string in the called function. That's OK.

> Why does passing a `char**` to a function that expects a `char const**` not work?

This sounds non-intuitive but there is a reason. Take this analogy with an `int`.

```
const int a = 10;
void foo(int const ** ap)
{
   *ap = &a;
}

void bar()
{
   int * p = NULL;
   foo(&p);
   *p = 20;
}
```

If you were allowed to use that, you are able to modify `a`, which is `const`, in `bar` indirectly.

That's why `&p`, whose type is `int**`, is not allowed to be cast to `int const**` implicitly.

Comment: Is there a way to specify that ap won't be copied to another pointer? Such as using the `restrict` keyword? Or are there more scenarios.

Comment: @jake, I don't think use of `restrict` is going to resolve the `const` vs non-`const` issue.

Comment: I just tried it and it seemed not to work. I guess my logic was `restrict` says that only the given pointer will point at memory, but that doesn't really work and it doesn't fix the issue at hand.