# Passing char ** to function accepting const char ** not allowed

Tags: c, string, pointers, compiler-errors, constraints

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning), but I am still not clear:

Something like:

```
#include <stddef.h>

size_t
foo(const char ** str)
{
  size_t i = 0;
  while (*str[0])
    i++;
  return i;
}

int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  foo(argv);
}
```

compiled as

```
$ gcc main.c
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:14:7: warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   14 |   foo(argv);
      |       ^~~~
      |       |
      |       char **
main.c:4:19: note: expected 'const char **' but argument is of type 'char **'
    4 | foo(const char ** str)
```

My fundamental question is: why can't I make something more `const`? What I am looking to accomplish is to say: I will not modify the characters, in this function.

To me, this seems different than the case the other answer gave, where you finagle your way into violating the `const` nature of a `char`.

Comment: "What I am looking to accomplish is to say: I will not modify the characters, in this function." C doesn't let you conveniently express this promise. In C++ you can write `const char* const* str` and it works perfectly fine, but alas C lacks implicit conversion from `T**` to `const T* const*`.

Comment: FYI... `while (*str[0])    i++;` is an infinite loop inside your `foo` function.  I'm not sure if that matters to what you are asking.  But I assume you really mean `while (*str[i]) i++;`

Comment: @user129393192, "why can't I make something more const" --> IIRC, C23 has an update to cope with this issue and allow it.

Comment: But then what would happen to the issue Eric mentioned in his answer? @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @user129393192 Concerning detailed explanation of  C23, best to wait for it to be released first.

Answer (score 0):

> My fundamental question is: why can't I make something more `const`?

A `char **` is a pointer to `char *`. Changing it to `const char **` does not make it a pointer to a `const` of the type `char *`; that would be `char * const *`. It changes it to be a pointer to a different type.

You can change `char **` to `char * const *`; an implicit conversion of that type will be accepted.

The issue is:

- The type `char *` is protected from being assigned a `const char *`. Given `char *p;` and `const char *cp;`, `p = cp;` is not allowed.
- The type `const char *` does not have that protection, because it is of course okay to assign a `const char *` to a `const char *`.
- If you change `char **` to `const char **`, you are removing protection.
- Given `char *pp = &p;`, `pp` points to a protected thing.
- If `pp` is passed to `void foo(const char **cpp)`, the type `const char **cpp` says `*cpp` is not protected. Therefore `foo` can do `*cpp = &cp;`, which changes `pp` to point to a `const char *`, which should not be allowed.

> To me, this seems different than the case the other answer gave,…

No, it is the same:

```
static const char *s = "Test";


void foo(const char **cpp)
{
    *cpp = s;
}


#include <stddef.h>


int main(void)
{
    char *p = NULL;
    char **pp = &p;
    foo(pp);  // Pass "char **" for "const char **", which is disallowed.

    *p = 0; //  Now p points to s, so this attempts to change a const char.
}
```

Comment: I was not able to follow the issue. Specifically, what protection are you removing?

Comment: @user129393192: Given `char *p;` and `const char *cp;`, `p = cp;` is not allowed. A `char *` is protected from being assigned a value of type `const char *`.

Comment: Is there a typo in the bullet points? I cannot make sense of it still. Specifically, should the fourth have `char ** pp = &p`? And the 3rd, how do you remove protection by assigning `char**` to a `const char**`, that seems like additional protection and is the main point of my confusion, which I think relates to the 4th, where you say `pp` points to a protected thing.