# Why doesn't strtol() and related functions' second argument point to const data?

Tags: c++, c

Is there any good reason why the second argument to `strtol()`, `strtoul()`, `strtod()` and related functions is a `char **`, instead of a `const char **`?

It seems to me that if we're converting a string that is pointed to by a `const char *` (first argument), a pointer to non-const data accessed to such a string can lead to problems.

As these functions are, code such as the one below, although clearly invalid, will merrily compile in both C and C++ even with several warning options on (in GCC, `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    static const char text[]="1234 seconds";
    char *eon;
    long n=strtol(text, &eon, 10);
    *eon='\0';
    return n;
}
```

**Note**

I imagine that a possible explanation is that the the functions only consider constant the characters used in the conversion, and not necessarily those adjacent to it. However, I still think getting a pointer to non-constant data through a pointer to constant data without an explicit cast doesn't make much sense. So little sense, that it is not possible to re-implement such functions without using at least one cast to remove the `const` qualifier.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: For compatibility with C.

Comment: `const` wasn't invented yet at the time these functions were introduced. And now it can't be added because code that actually passes `char**` would fail to compile. While `char*` is convertible to `const char*`. `char**` is not convertible to `const char**` (for a good reason).

Comment: Also see [Why does passing char** as const char** generate a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562845/why-does-passing-char-as-const-char-generate-a-warning).  It's a subtle issue, and I find it quite annoying, but what can you do...